# Css background image cover, fight height and width

Tags: html, css

I have this **html** code to create a background to my `div`:

```
<div id="secondBigDiv">test</div>
```

This is my **css** code :

```
#secondBigDiv{
    background: url(../images/myposts/background.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This code works perfectly as I want but the problem is:

- I couldn't fit the height also, when i scroll down I find empty white spaces because my background image didn't fit the height, it fits the width.

Any help?

Comment: Try to remove the `fixed` tag from your background.

Comment: Not a fix for height problem. You have typo in code, missing space before no-repeat

Comment: The given information does not explain the situation completely. Please provide a more complete example, preferably as jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting each image property in its own line. `background-repeat,background-attachment, etc`

May not change anything but seems to work for me.